# Não aparece componentes do xCode no simulador?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, iphone

Estou com um problema com o `xCode` no `Swift`. De uma hora pra outra não quer aparecer no simulador novos componentes que incluo no `viewController`.

Por exemplo: Se eu colocar um simples `button` na tela, ao compilar no simulador o este mesmo `button` não aparece. Por que isso está acontecendo?

Comment: Ele deve ter ficado por trás de outro componente no interface builder. Abre a janela a esquerda que exibe todos os componentes na tela e arraste ele para o final da lista.

Comment: Outra possibilidade é que seja um problema de cache. Tenta fazer primeiro `Product -> Clean` e depois rodar, talvez funcione.

Comment: Olá, eu cheguei a ver e não esta atras do view não.  Não sei de da pra ver no link abaixo a imagem como esta....http://f.666kb.com/i/d2bj0cncapn4dzoba.gif

Comment: Oi, também fiz um clean e nada de funcionar, e o mais curioso é que eu estou mudando a posição dos componentes dentro do view e na hora de mostrar no simulador ele fica como se não tivesse mudado a posição, mantendo a anterior, agora se por exemplo num imageview eu mudar de imagem e rodar o simulador aparece a nova imagem, se eu excluir o componente ao rodar o simulador não aparece o componente, mais se eu alterar as posições dos componentes no simulador não altera, ja reiniciei o xcode o simulador ja reiniciei o mac e nada. Não estou entendendo. Obrigado.

Comment: Então pode ser um problema de layout, autolayout e size class estão habilitados?

Comment: Sim estão habilitados.

Answer (score 1):

Descobri aqui o problema estava mostrando em wCompact e hCompact 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai mudei para wAny e hAny e resolveu
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]